# Após um create, atualizar um array com dados de um get ou incrementar a response no array?

Tags: angular, single-page-application

Supondo que eu tenha uma tabela mostrando dados de um array, ao inserir um novo elemento no banco de dados através de uma requisição `POST`, qual a melhor forma para atualizar os dados na tela?

Sempre fico em dúvida entre realizar um `GET` novamente, para então, incluir os novos registros:

```
this.service.save(element).subscribe(res => {
  this.getLista()
});
```

Dessa forma acredito que possui a vantagem de inserir além do elemento que acabou de ser criado, o elemento que outras pessoas criaram entre o momento do `save` e a chamada do `get` porém seria uma requisição a mais e dependendo da quantidade de dados.

ou pegar o retorno da api, que geralmente é o elemento que foi criado, e insiro no arrray:

```
this.service.save(element).subscribe(res => {
  this.array.push(res.data)
});
```

Dessa forma acrescenta instantaneamente sem depender do servidor, porém pode ser que a lista não esteja totalmente atualizada.

Qual das duas formas é a mais recomendada para atualizar dados que acabaram de ser adicionados/excluidos/atualizados?

Comment: Cara sua  pergunta é ampla e principalmente depende de cada caso, eu faço sempre um get pra certificar de pegar todas as alterações, da segunda maneira não sei se vc estaria com a lista 100% atualizada, só que faria diferente, eu faria o get no **ngOnInit()** e no post se ocorrer tudo bem aí eu dou um ngOnInit() par recarregar e atualizar o componente

Answer (score -1):

Amigo, essa pergunta pode ser bastante explorada, você pode utilizar controle de estado para fazer isso. Existe algumas bibliotecas disponíveis.

[ngxs](https://www.ngxs.io/)
[ngrx](https://ngrx.io/)

Você dispararia as actions que atualizaria suas listas.

Você pode usar o próprio rxjs, criando um "service singleton" que compartilhar seus Subject ou BehaviorSubject, onde os componentes dariam um next no valo, disparando as atualizações para sua lista, entre componentes.

[subject](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subject) [behaviorsubject](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/BehaviorSubject)

De uma olhada nas soluções e use a que melhor encaixe no seu problema

Comment: minha dúvida é a melhor forma de atualizar a lista, por exemplo, uma action que realiza um get() pra trazer os registros ou uma action que eu mando o novo objeto criado e ele atualiza o array

Comment: Então, existe varias formas de fazer, todas são validas, tem que ver a que melhor encaixa n o seu problema, você criar um service que atualiza a lista usando rxjs é o meio mais fácil e rápido, onde a lista principal que é apresentada fica escutando o subject do service, quando você pegar o retorno do get, ele dispara um setNewItem, nele tem o next value do service, automaticamente a lista apresenta os dados, isso dizendo que você está trabalhando com vários componentes, em um component apenas não faria sentido

Comment: E com o controle de estado, você saberia se o item foi alterado ou não, se as lista forem idênticas, não teria disparo de actions